# PCA on large and high dimensional dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, pca

I am trying to perform a PCA analysis on a large dataset (410 000 entries and 32 000 features) in python, but `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` does not work, as the underlying LAPACK implementation can't handle as much data as i have. It throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    model.fit(x_std.transform(deep_data))
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py", line 344, in fit
    self._fit(X)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py", line 416, in _fit
    return self._fit_full(X, n_components)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py", line 447, in _fit_full
    U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py", line 125, in svd
    compute_uv=compute_uv, full_matrices=full_matrices)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/scipy/linalg/lapack.py", line 605, in _compute_lwork
    raise ValueError("Too large work array required -- computation cannot "
ValueError: Too large work array required -- computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK.
```

I have also tried `sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA` but as I dont have any issues with RAM it did not solve my problem, it only introduced more as it does not allow me to have all 32000 components if my batch size is smaller than that.

Is there any other implementation of PCA that can handle this much data? I don't necessarily need all 410 000 samples, but i need at least 32 000 so that i can analyze all principal components.

Comment: Maybe use random selected subsets of the samples of a size as large as possible and repeat that many times, then kind of average the outcomes.

Comment: The problem is that i want to analyze all 32000 components to plot the cumulative sum of variance that all 32000 components contribute with. This cannot be done with random sampling @Trilarion

Comment: I tried this solution but it has the same problem as sk.learn; numpy uses lapack in its linear algebra operations (eigh, solve) which crashes on my data. @SergeyBushmanov

Comment: Maybe you can look into the algorithm used to compute the PCA and see if some in-memory operations can be stored in a file instead and therefore achieve a solution by yourself. The lack of answers seems to suggest that it's not obvious.

Comment: I suspect for this amount of data you need to have 256Mb+ RAM. Or try out of memory frameworks like Spark. As a side note, 32'000 features seems to be impractical.

Comment: As these operations are hid away deep in the numpy implementation within the LAPACK package (which is written in Fortran) I think that this will be too hard for me. The sci-kit implementaion worked with 11000 componetns, which has to make due for me. Thanks for your answers anyway! @Trilarion

Comment: The computations needed more than 256 gigabyte of ram with all 400,000 samples. I tried spark later but it did not work either (haha). I have to make due with 11,000 features. And as to your sidenote, yes it is impractical, but the features comes from a deep neural network and i do not know what they mean or represent. That is what i am trying to find out! Thank you for your time. @SergeyBushmanov

Comment: Try 11000 features and and then another 11000 and then another 11000 and only keep the most 1/3 contributing to variance of each of these runs and then run the PCA again of the ones you kept. Surely a feature that is not significant when used with other features will still be not significant when used with even more features together.